# Python/Glue - use spark session for entire code (access variables from another class)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I want to share entire `SparkSession` for a code I'm working on by using `getOrCreate()` method.
I'm stuck with an error when trying to access `gc` instantiated in `Context`:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Context' has no attribute 'gc'
```

Goal is to have SparkSession isolated into a class and used whenever I would need to rather then packing everything into one. Tried inheritance, calling `Context` class directly in `RDSClient` to no avail.

**UPDATE**
I came up with working solution but still wonder if there is a better way to handle it.

```
import sys
import re
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import awsglue
import pyspark
import boto3
import pymssql
import pandas

class Context():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sc = SparkContext()
        self.gc = GlueContext(self.sc.getOrCreate())
        self.spark = self.gc.spark_session
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_parameters(*args):
        return getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["dynamodb_metadata_table"])

class RDSClient(Context):

    def __init__(self, ctx):
        self.gc = ctx.gc

    def rds_frame():
        tbl = self.gc.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
                    connection_type = "sqlserver", 
                    connection_options = {"url": "jdbc:sqlserver://blablabla.rds.amazonaws.com:1433/dwh", 
                                            "user": "", 
                                            "password": "",
                                            "dbtable": "dbo.tble_name"},
                    transformation_ctx = "glue_df")
        return tbl.printSchema()

def main():

    job = Context()

    args = job.get_parameters()
    metadata = args["dynamodb_metadata_table"]

    RDSClient.rds_frame(job)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach looks good. However, Irrespective how you separate them into classes, its all one script at the end and every Glue job will end up having same code. Kinda boiler plate. If you have 100 scripts, all of them will have this.

If your intention is to modularize the code to make it better for unit testing, i think your code is good enough. If your intention is to have a central library with all the common classes & functions, then i would suggest to package it and add it as library to each Glue script. That way, you can set a standard process to set up the context in Glue jobs.

And, move any common properties to  job parameters, so they wont be exposed in the script. Such as JDBC Url, user name, passwords etc. or by using secret manager for passwords.

These are just my thoughts.

Comment: These are very useful points! As for parameters, yes - they will be stored in a proper manner. For now it is made this way due to testing core functionality. For now it will be sliced into modules. Currently I will have only one Glue script but will look into packaging it for future re-use.